# Are Gorn and Tamarian related?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-tos, star-trek-eu

Are the Gorn species and the Tamarian species related in the Star Trek Universe or other non-canon Star Trek references? I see some visual similarities between the two species.

Comment: Why WOULD they be? They look totally different & have completely different cultures. If you have reason to believe they might be related, please cite the reason in the question.

Comment: @JMFB: What is your basis for comparing the two?  Did you encounter this theory somewhere?  You should provide some background in the question as to why you suspect them to be related.

Comment: @Omegacron Sorry, re-read my post as I have edited it, and see if that helps explain with my question.

Comment: @Praxis Again Sorry, please re-read my post and see if that helps explain my question any better.

Comment: @JMFB - Please don't edit your question to attempt to comment on answers.

Comment: @JMFB - Can you explain what specific visual similarities you see that made you think this? I don't really see any similarities in Daft's picture besides the fact that they are hairless and both have (fairly different-looking) ridges in the center of their heads, both of which I'm sure could be found in plenty of other Trek aliens.

Comment: @Hypnosifl I tried but once again richard took all of my edits out and it's getting tiring. I'm not going to dedicate my life to this. I posted an explanation, added photos, and explained my reasoning. But Richard deleted all of it.If I attempt to again, he'll simply delete my edits. Sorry

Comment: @JMFB: I missed the additional edits you are referring to, but the way your question stands right now (with "I see some visual similarities between the two species"), it seems fine to me.

Comment: @Praxis Yeah I guess so. There are visual similarities. But I went into further explanation and posted some photos. It took awhile to do all of that and then to have a moderator just flippantly delete it for no real reason... In any event, I love the site and it's interesting to see what other people are thinking and how they tackle explaining questions I have, but my time is too valuable to spend it here and then have my efforts deleted by the whim of a single person.

Comment: @JMFB - Your old edits are visible if you click "edited _ hours ago" under your post. But I don't see anything explaining what specific similarities you see between Gorn and Tamarians in any of your previous edits, I just see a long discussion about how Klingon makeup changed. If you just explain what specific visual features you think the Gorn and Tamarians have in common, I don't think you'll get edited.

Comment: @Hypnosifl Well I posted a bunch of photos that went with the explanation. It doesn't matter. I have a bunch more questions from some episodes I've been watching and just some other generic questions I have. If he keeps deleting them, marking them as duplicates when they're not, etc.  I'll probably just stop posting questions and answers and not waste my time with it anymore. I think I've made some valuable contributions in the past couple months since I joined and became an active member, but the fun of it is getting sucked out of me.

Comment: @JMFB - Your photos were all photos *of Klingons*--they were only useful for making the general point that makeup can evolve with time on Trek, but didn't tell the readers anything about *what **specific** visual similarities you saw between Gorn and Tamarians*. The rest of us aren't seeing any, so your question is just going to seem arbitrary and strange (like if you had asked "are the Cardassians and the Gorn related?") unless you at least *try* to give some explanation of what specific visual similarities you think you see.

Comment: @JMFB : Having looked through the edit history, I have to agree with Richard and Hypnosifl. Richard is just doing his job as a diamond moderator --- a job he does quite well. Sure, this site is meant to be fun (and we certainly do have fun!), but it also has a *format* and *structure*. It is not a free-for-all forum. We all work together to improve each other's contributions, and users who have been around for a while help out the newer users. It's good to learn to trust the hard work of the moderators and to avoid getting defensive, as part of respecting the overarching goals of the site.

Comment: They both had reptilian features, to me at least. They both had ridges over their ears, similar ears, greenish coloring, bipeds, etc. They look similar. If the pictures of the two below confuse that point for some reason. I showed that within tos Klingons changed, and in each series and the movies they changed. If somebody saw the pictures in the order I placed them, they might see that if they took into consideration makeup and special effects into account, the two look similar.

Comment: @Praxis - *Quite* well? High praise indeed... Not!

Comment: @Richard : Oh darn.  It's my time in North America, suppressing the Englishman in me, you see.  "Quite" has replaced *very* for me, as is the convention on this side of the pond.  Good intentions, good intentions....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Technically, probably yes.**

(But we don't know for sure)

According to a TNG episode "[The Chase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chase_%28Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation%29)" (season 6, episode 20), a lone ancient race of beings scouted our galaxy before there was any humanoid life there except for them.  They are responsible for seeding various planets with their own DNA, out of which all humanoid life forms have developed.  Therefore all of the races including Humans, Romulans, Cardassians, Klingons, etc. (and presumably Gorn and Tamarians) share a common ancestor.

Comment: +1 to this. You are technically correct, the [best kind of correct](http://www.quickmeme.com/img/62/62f538b129e13afc6c7d9b9278b63f63f4c91e1f8fd1077c36e088039bf538f8.jpg).

Comment: @MarkRogers Fair enough.  I modified the answer.  Also, Ron D. Moore said this race could have been the Preservers, but he intentionally left their identity vague.

Comment: @Chahk - +1 It was nice of you to address my quibble.

Comment: Very clever! 

Answer (score 8):

#### Almost definitely not

The [Gorn](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Gorn) are lizard people *(with insect eyes?)*.

[image: Gorn]

The [Tamarians](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Tamarian) are not lizard people. They might be related to bats though, judging by their noses at least.

[image]

Comment: LOL, I love the term "Lizard People", very scientific! What would the Lizard people call us? Silly Puddy people? @daft I edited my question, and used some images to try and explain my thinking.

Comment: @JMFB: probably Chimp People.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's safe to say the Tamarians were not meant to be updated versions of the Gorn, although they may be technically related in the sense Chahk mentioned (though I don't think this is clear--the Gorn look different enough from most "humanoids" that their basic body configuration might just be a case of [convergent evolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergent_evolution)). Aside from the fact that there seems to be almost no visual similarity between them in the pictures posted by Daft, the [Gorn wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gorn) mentions that an updated version of a Gorn was shown in an *Enterprise* episode, "In a Mirror, Darkly Part II", and they weren't depicted as looking anything like the Tamarians:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the fact that the episodes TOS:Arena and TNG:Darmok are often used to highlight the differences between the first two Star Trek series, as well as the differences between Kirk and Picard, there are no connection between the races.

Comment: Any references?

Comment: Yes, references? Not just for the no connection, but how they're used to highlight differences between the two shows.

Comment: What references do you need but watching both episodes? Kirk beats the hell out of the Gorn (oh wait, it's the other way around o.O but anyways brute force is key here), Picard talks and is getting talked to an understanding. Other than that: do you want a reference cited for there being exactly NO connection between the two races? And if this reference is not provided you're going to take its non-existance as a proof of the contrary? "Fascinating!"

Comment: @Ghanima Actually I thought he meant the differences in special effects and costumes. If he's referring to Kirk being violent and Picard not using this episode...I totall disagree. Kirk had no choice. He was being attacked by an alien he could not communicate with, it was complete self defense. Picard has fought on many occasions, if you'd like me to list some of them I can. I'll give the dialog from the episode in another comment to refute 100% what you are saying.

Comment: "KIRK: No. No, I won't kill you. Maybe you thought you were protecting yourself when you attacked the outpost. 
(He throws the dagger away, stands up and shouts to the sky) 
KIRK: No, I won't kill him! Do you hear? You'll have to get your entertainment someplace else!

METRON: By sparing your helpless enemy who surely would have destroyed you, you demonstrated the advanced trait of mercy...I sent him back to his ship. If you like, I shall destroy him for you.
KIRK: No. That won't be necessary. We can talk. Maybe reach an agreement."   HARDLY KIRK TRYING TO "beat the hell" out of the Gorn.

Comment: @JMFB, I don't think that this is the right place for this kind of discussion. And yes, I do know that Kirk did not kill the Gorn or anyone else (hope this holds true) in cold blood! Other than that please let me stick to my own flat picture of the three tools of Kirk's conflict resolution: 1) punch it (if it is a male alien), 2) talk it into self destruction (if it is an AI), 3) seduce it (if it is a female alien) ;)

Comment: @Ghanima why isn't this the right place? If his answer is that these two episodes were designed to show that Kirk is violent and resorts to violence first, and that Picard is a peaceful person who doesn't resort to violence. I can give many examples of the exact opposite. I gave the exact example from this exact episode. As for Kirk's relationship with women, TNG simply breaks Kirk into two characters, Picard and Riker. Kirk had to do a lot more acting and cover a lot more roles. Kirk had more air time for two reasons, length of the episodes and # of characters.